# Does JQuery Datepicker not work in the same web form that has a User Control?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, user-controls, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an ASP.NET Web form that has a user control i.e. Loading.ascx, which just contains an .gif in the centre of the page.  This is used to show a loading image when the user clicks on any button/link in the page.

The page also has a asp:TextBox, which is linked to JQuery Datepicker.  While running the program, I get the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDefaults' of undefined**

Initially I did some research in Stack Overflow, but none of the solutions worked for me.  While doing some random work, I removed the .ascx Register command from the aspx page:

**<%@ Register Src="~/Common/Loading.ascx" TagName="LoadingScreen" TagPrefix="UC" %>**

and the datepicker did not have any problem running.  All issues got resolved.  Can anyone please help me understand what is going wrong when I try to use a .ascx file in a .aspx with JQuery Datepicker?

Below is the code of Loading.ascx,

```
> <%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"
> CodeBehind="Loading.ascx.vb" Inherits="eLearnWebRole.Loading" %>
> <script
> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"
> type="text/javascript"></script>
> 
> <style>    #divLoading{
>       display: none; 
>       width: 100%; 
>       background-color: rgba(255,246,246,0.5); 
>       top: 0px; 
>       left: 0px; 
>       position: absolute; 
>       text-align: center; 
>       vertical-align: middle;
>       z-index: 99999;    }
>        #divLoadingImage{
>       position: absolute; 
>       display: block;
>       width: 200px;
>       height: 200px;    }
> 
> </style>
> 
> <div id="divLoading">    <div id="divLoadingImage">
>       <asp:Image ID="imgLoading" AlternateText="LoadMsg" ImageUrl="~/Common/Images/Loading.gif" runat="server" />    </div>
> </div>
> 
> <script>    $(document).ready(function () {
> 
>       $("#divLoadingImage").css({
>          "left": (($(window).width() - $("#divLoadingImage").width()) / 2) + "px",
>          "top": (($(window).height() - $("#divLoadingImage").height()) / 2) + "px"
>       });
> 
>       $("#divLoading").height($(document).height());
> 
>       $(window).resize(function () {
>          $("#divLoading").height($(window).height());
> 
>          $("#divLoadingImage").css({
>             "left": (($(window).width() - $("#divLoadingImage").width()) / 2) + "px",
>             "top": (($(window).height() - $("#divLoadingImage").height()) / 2) + "px"
>          });
>       });
> 
>    }); </script>
```

Below is the snippet of the Aspx code that had the .ascx code registered:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="StudentActivityReport.aspx.vb" Inherits="eLearnWebRole.StudentActivityReport" %>

<%--Cannot use Loading.ascx with pages that have datepicker.  Have to find an alternative to use both loading.ascx and datepicker in the same page--%>
<%--<%@ Register Src="~/Common/Loading.ascx" TagName="LoadingScreen" TagPrefix="UC" %>--%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <title>Page Title goes here</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/jquery-ui.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" />
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script src="Script/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
.
.
.
.
                     <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoViewFrom" Value="Between" GroupName="rdogroupWeeklyOrViewFrom" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:RadioButton>View From:  
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtCalFromDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                     To:
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtCalToDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
.
.
.
.
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the .js file that has the error with setting defaults to datepicker:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
.
.
.
.
   $.datepicker.setDefaults({    //Throws an error here.
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      firstDay: 1,
      nextText: "Next",
      prevText: "Prev",
      showAnim: "fold",
      showOn: "focus"
   });
.
.
.

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to load the `js` that was written in UserControl into the aspx page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You Don't Need to add the `Jquery` files again in the Usercontrol as
   you already referenced them in the aspx page where you are calling
   this UserControl.
2. Try to move your  `$("#divLoadingImage").css()` to the aspx Page